# Autocompletar texto de un input en base a datos almacenados en Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Buenas, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de que al ir ingresando caracteres en un `input` de tipo `text` se despliegue una barra con sugerencias previamente ingresadas, usando `JQuery`, `javascript`, etc.
Aclaro que no quiero obtener datos de una base de datos.
Llevo tiempo buscando esto pero no encuentro una solución. 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: O sea quieres que cada vez que el usuario ingrese un texto, éste se guarde en localStorage para futuras búsquedas, y en las interacciones posteriores, el contenido de localStorage sirva para sugerir textos.

Comment: Sí, eso mismo, digamos que te irá sugiriendo palabras que hayan sido previamente ingresadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente: Cada vez que el usuario haga *submit* en el formulario o haga la acción que deseas, guardas el dato en `localStorage` y al principio de la aplicación lees los datos guardados previamente:

> Nota: He usado `autocomplete` de `jQuery ui`, puedes usar la librería que desees.

**Código HTML**

```
<input id="search" type="search" />
<input id="button" type="button" value="Buscar" />
```

**Código JavaScript**

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
var results = (storage.getItem("searches")) ? JSON.parse(storage.getItem("searches")) : [];
var search = $("#search");
var button = $("#button");

search.autocomplete({
    source: results
});

button.on("click", function () {

    var str = search.val();

    if (results.indexOf(str) < 0) {

        results.push(search.val());

        storage.setItem("searches", JSON.stringify(results));

    }

    search.val("");

});
```

Aquí te dejo un [Codepen](http://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/pegrBP) para que puedas probar la funcionalidad.

Comment: Hola y gracias por comentar, voy a probar de esta forma también ya que por lo que vi es más corta pero logra lo que estoy buscando, saludos!

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te ayude. Un saludo ;)

Answer (score 5):

Una forma es la siguiente:

- En el evento `focus` del input: cargar lista de sugerencias
- En el evento `blur`: eliminar lista de sugerencias
- En el evento `input`: iterar la lista de nodos y comprobar si cada nodo contiene una parte del texto ingresado. En caso afirmativo, muestra la sugerencia y en caso contrario, la esconde.

Este código no solo funciona con `local/sessionStorage`, si no también puedes obtener la lista de sugerencias desde una API, por ejemplo.

```js
let suggestions = [
  'javascript',
  'css',
  'scss',
  'jquery',
  'php',
  'python',
  'node.js',
  'html5'
];

let input = document.querySelector('.search input');
let searchBox = document.querySelector('.search-box');
let suggestionList = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
  //let suggestions = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('suggestions'));
  fillSuggestionList(suggestions);
  searchBox.classList.add('visible');
});

input.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  searchBox.classList.remove('visible');
  clearSuggestionList();
});

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let enteredText = this.value.toLowerCase();
  let suggestions = suggestionList.children;

  [].forEach.call(suggestions, function(suggestion) {
    let suggestionContent = suggestion.textContent;

    if (enteredText.length && suggestionContent.includes(enteredText)) {
      suggestion.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      suggestion.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});

function fillSuggestionList(suggestions) {
  suggestions.forEach(function(suggestion) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = suggestion;
    suggestionList.appendChild(li);
  });
}

function clearSuggestionList() {
  while (suggestionList.firstChild) {
    suggestionList.removeChild(suggestionList.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 .75rem;
  transition: all .25s var(--ease);
  width: 100%;
}

.input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 100, 255, .5);
  outline: none;
}

.input-addon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.input-addon .icon {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.0625rem 0.1875rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  height: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .25s var(--ease);
}

.input-addon .icon:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
  height: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  width: 2px;
}

.input-addon .icon i {
  color: #777;
}

.input-addon .input {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.search {
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.input-addon .input:focus+.icon {
  border-color: rgba(0, 100, 250, .5);
}

.search-box {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .23), 0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  padding: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transition: all .25s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-box.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 140%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.suggestions {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.suggestions li {
  color: #555;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="search">
  <div class="input-addon">
    <input type="search" class="input">
    <figure class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="search-box">
    <ul class="suggestions">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Nota:** el código usa ES6, por lo que si das soporte a ES5 cambiar `let` por `var` e `includes` por `indexOf(str) !== -1`.

Comment: Hola y gracias por comentar, disculpas por demorar tanto en responder pero he estado ocupado y recién pude ver las respuestas, sin duda es lo que estoy buscando, de nuevo te agradezco, saludos!